# Downloading File from IE using VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am currently working on a VBA code that retrieves the top file from this website  (http://infopost.bwpmlp.com/Posting/default.aspx?Mode=Display&Id=27&tspid=100000). I am able to click on the button using Javascript in my code, and I am able to click on open after the download is kicked off. However, I am having trouble saving the file. Because the workbook is being pulled from a website there really isn't a way to set it to the active workbook that I can think of. Currently when I do ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs the code is saving the blank workbook that I am testing the code out of. The file I downloaded seems to not open until the entire code is done running even after I try putting in breaks. Anyone have any ideas? My code is below. Thanks!

```
 Option Explicit
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim h As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr


Sub Texas_Gas()
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim ie As Object
Dim IeHandle As Long, FileDownloadHandle As Long, OpenButtonHandle As Long, IePopupBarHandle As Long
Dim AutoMode As Boolean, FileDownloadClassicPopup As Boolean, DownloadComplete As Boolean
Dim Timeout As Date
Dim strSPICE As String, strLink As String
Dim PopupGap As Integer, i As Integer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

DownloadComplete = False
    FileDownloadClassicPopup = False
    FileDownloadHandle = 0
    IePopupBarHandle = 0


With ie
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://infopost.bwpmlp.com/Posting/default.aspx?    Mode=Display&Id=27&tspid=100000"
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With

ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(""dgITMatrix:0:lnkBtnDownload"", """", true, """", """", false, true))"


Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set o = New CUIAutomation
h = ie.Hwnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)


If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)

Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\Cap_Rel\raw_scrapes\Texas_Gas_Transmission\parsed\Texas_Gas_Transmission_CapRel" & Format(Date - 1, "yyyymmdd") & "MACRO", FileFormat:=xlCSV

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actual need to open it?  Why not just use IE to save it?

Comment: I need to save it into a specific directory. I couldn't figure out how to use "Save As" in IE, and when I do save it only saves it in downloads.